# Transferring matlab data into C#

Tags: c#, matlab

I've called **matlab** functions from **C#** program. It returns an object. I want to display the data in object o. o has "onion" stored in it. I used the following code to display "onion" on the console but it gives the following output:

*Displaying results:*

```
System.Object[,]
```

*THE CODE USED:*

```
        object o = matlab.GetVariable("f", "base");
        string s = o.ToString();
        string ss=Convert.ToString(s);
        //matlab.GetFullMatrix("f", "base", ref cr, ref ci);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Displaying results: ");
        System.Console.WriteLine(ss);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Objet o, what is it. Is it a string or array of strings?

Comment: It is less clear to judge where your problem is, as it is hardly to tell what "onion" means in your code.

Comment: What is the type of variable "f"?

Comment: object is the data type. "onion" is the string returned from a matlab function, stored in f. That variable is then stored in object o. When debugging, o does have "onion" present in it, but when i try to display it on the console it displays System.Object[,] instead of "onion"

Comment: the return type of "f" is cell, in matlab.

Answer (score 0):

As o's type is System.Object[,], so it is fair that o.ToString() equals "System.Object[,]".
If you want to display the value of o, do not call o.ToString().

Pseudo code below (not tested)

```
   var a=O[0,0] as string;
   var b=O[1,0] as int;
   var str_A=a.ToString();
   var str_B=b.ToString();
```

See if this works for you.

Comment: o cannot be accessed in the form o[,]. It gives an error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: @user2134669 
What is type of O in C#?

Comment: the data type is 'object' in C#:

object o = matlab.GetVariable("f", "base");

Comment: From your output, it seems O is of type object[,], try casting o from object to object[,] first.